# Transistor C114 markings

Tags: markings

What are the letters below the marking C114 on the package of the transistors?

For example one can find

\$E.SB, \quad  E.S\bar C, \quad T.S\bar B\$

[image]

Are those transistors all equivalent?

Is this type of marking standard among other components? Any advice on where to gather information on this topic?

Comment: It's probably a date or lot code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab a [data sheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.net/datasheet-pdf/view-marking/1343426/LEIDITECH/DTC114ESA.html) and look up the markings: -

[image]

I'm sure if you need to understand the markings after the letter "E" (the code) either you'll find it in the DS or you can contact the supplier.

Comment: Ok thanks, i was confusing markings and part number. To find the datasheet associated with the marking, alldatasheet.net is always sufficient ?

Comment: I just type in the number on a google search but, my strong preference is a link to the direct source rather than these data sheet provider services.

Comment: Typing "c114", "c114 component" or "c114 markings" does not give accurate results. Any advice on some keywords ? English isn't my native language. Thanks a lot Andy.

Comment: That is all I did to find the data sheet. I think I typed in "C114 transistor".

Comment: But reading a number on a component, you don't know if it is a transistor or a triac or so. It is even more complicated when the number of terminals excesses three.

Comment: That's where experience comes in. I did actually recognize the number as a BJT transistor. Apart from anything else you referred to it as a transistor in your question.